# Stuck in a while loop while using if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a simple Guess the number game, and I'm stuck in an if statement in a while loop. here is the code.

I'm experiencing it at the Your guess it too high and the low one. I tried **break**ing it, but it simply stops the whole things

```
def guess_the_number():
    number = random.randrange(20)

    guessesMade = 0

    print('Take a guess')
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    while guessesMade < 6:
        if guess < number:
            print('Your guess is too low.')

        if guess > number:
            print('Your guess is too high.')

        if guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        print'You got it in', guessesMade, 'guess(es)! Congratulaions!'
    else:
        print'I\'m sorry, the number was', number
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never increment `guessesMade` so `guessesMade < 6` will always be `True`. You need to modify this value within your loop. You also need to move your prompt for user input into the loop

```
while guessesMade < 6:
    guess = int(input('Take a guess'))

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
        guessesMade += 1

    elif guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
        guessesMade += 1

    else:
        break
```

Comment: I have tried that already, it just prints it all again and doesn't ask the number

Comment: @Kasra I'm a time-traveler from 60 seconds in the future, so I get a head start!

Comment: guess cannot be three things at once